# Counting number of zeros in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, counting

I have the following data:

```
    htno         sub       marks        credits
      1           a          15            0
      1           b          10            0 
      1           c          25            4
      1           d          24            4
      1           e          22            2
      1           f          12            0
      2           a          22            4 
      2           b          15            0
      2           c          23            4
      2           d          18            2 
      2           e          20            4
      2           f          6             0
      3           a          22            4  n so on
```

i will provide a form to a user. If the user enters his halticket number "1", then it should display the output in this manner in PHP and MySQL:

```
            Number of Backlogs           Passed Subjects
                   3                           3
```

That means it should count the number of zeros and display the number of backlogs and count the number of non zeros and display the count of passed subjects.

How can I do this?

Comment: you forgot to paste your query here?

Comment: still ididnt write d query.. i am nt getting any idea to strt d query fr this...

Comment: @AryanManojRaj Your question was probably downvoted because it is a little unclear. However, you did provide sample data and a sample result set, and you explained what you wanted to achieve. With a little effort and patience, I was able to answer your question.

Comment: [Why was this question closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147068/why-was-this-question-closed-as-not-a-real-question)

Comment: I would say more "too localized" than "not a real question".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I stripped the trailing and leading spaces from your text-formatted data and created an equivalent sample schema using SQL Fiddle. The setup looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Grades
    (`htno` int, `sub` varchar(1), `marks` int, `credits` int)
;

INSERT INTO Grades
    (`htno`, `sub`, `marks`, `credits`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 15, 0),
    (1, 'b', 10, 0),
    (1, 'c', 25, 4),
    (1, 'd', 24, 4),
    (1, 'e', 22, 2),
    (1, 'f', 12, 0),
    (2, 'a', 22, 4),
    (2, 'b', 15, 0),
    (2, 'c', 23, 4),
    (2, 'd', 18, 2),
    (2, 'e', 20, 4),
    (2, 'f', 6, 0),
    (3, 'a', 22, 4)
;
```

I have made the following assumptions:

- Each row represents the attainment of a student in a subject.
- The "halticket number" unique identifies each student and is represented by the column `htno`.
- A value of zero in the `credits` column represents a subject in the student's "backlog".
- A value greater than zero in the `credits` column represents a "passed subject".

This query meets your requirements:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN credits = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Number of backlogs`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN credits > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Passed subjects`
FROM Grades
WHERE htno = 1;
```

We [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) from the Grades table all the rows for the student with halticket number 1 using a `WHERE` filter.

The first [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html) expression computes a new column that contains a 0 if credits is non-zero and contains a 1 otherwise.

The second `CASE` expression computes a new column that contains a 0 if credits is non-positive and contains a 1 otherwise.

You can imagine that the intermediate result would look like this:

```
[Case expression 1] [Case expression 2]
0   1
0   1
1   0
1   0
1   0
0   1
```

We treat the entire result set as a group for aggregation, and add up all the values in the first and second computed columns using the [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function.

The sum of the first column is 3, and the sum of the second column is 3.

This gives you the final result set.

You can experiment with my interactive solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1282/2).